# PHP CodeIgniter Not Work New Page

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello i want to new page in CodeIgniter but no work where is problem

application/controllers/Test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function test()
    {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

application/views/test.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
just test page
```

and show me not found this page - image:

[image]

[image]

Comment: add construct method in your controller

Comment: try http://localhost/yourprojectname/index.php/Test/test

Comment: i think you need to read documentation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/\

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller needs a bit more information for PHP 5.6, ie:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct()
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('test');
    }
}
```

Also, you need to make sure your Apache mod_rewrite is working correctly.  If not, the URL would be something like:

`http://localhost/index.php?/test/`

If you want to rewrite your URLs, so you could access `http://localhost/test/` then you'd need to add a `.htaccess` file to the same directory as index.php.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```